# I'm trying to have a msgbox display numbers 1-100 with an increment a user inputs. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, inc As Integer, results() As Integer
Dim text As String

n = 100

inc = InputBox("Please enter increment")

ReDim results(0 To n) As Integer

For i = 1 To n Step 1

results(i) = inc + i

text = results(i)

Next i

MsgBox (text)

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I''m trying to have it all displayed in one message like "1,2,3,4,5,6....."

Comment: Change the text = ... line to `Text = Text & "," & results(i)`

Comment: That helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, inc As Integer, results() As Integer
Dim text As String

n = 100

inc = InputBox("Please enter increment")

ReDim results(0 To n) As Integer

For i = 1 To n Step 1

results(i) = inc + i

Next i

text = Join(results, ",")
MsgBox text

End Sub
```

The `Join()` function will join a single dimension array using a given delimiter and return a string.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: If it worked - don't forget to mark as answer with the green tick on the left :)

Comment: Yep, got it. Still new to the site and learning all the rules. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

An increment, as I understand it, is a stepsize - the difference between consecutive values. Thus, the code should be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, inc As Integer, results() As Integer
Dim text As String

n = 100
inc = InputBox("Please enter increment")
ReDim results(1 To n) As Integer  ' not: (0 to n)

For i = 1 To n Step inc
    results(i) = i
Next i
text = Join(results, ",")
MsgBox text
End Sub
```

Comment: _theoretically_ it should be `0 To n-1` as VBA by default uses a zero-based index. But either way works just fine.